# Verifying method call with different arguments using argument matchers eq() fails complaining Argument(s) are different

Tags: mockito, junit4, verify

I'm writing a test case to validate execution with specific method call with specific arguments. The test need to pass only when **specific values are passed** (for ex. only pass when status & ParseError is passed) to the method. Below is the code snippet for the test to verify:

```
Mockito.verify(exeImpl, Mockito.atLeastOnce()).setData(eq("status"), eq("ParseError"));
```

and case failed with below:

```
Argument(s) are different! Wanted: 
exeImpl.setData(
  "status",
  "ParseError"
);
-> at com.TestTask.testRest(TestTask.java:280)
Actual invocation has different arguments:
exeImpl.setData(
  "status",
  "Error"
);
-> at 
com.TestTask.setDefault(Task.java:186)
```

The actual invocation which is mentioned in the error is because the setData is called with **default values** before starting the business logic. After the business logic is done, the setData is called again to set the result.

And setData has below definition

```
setData(final String arg1, final Object arg2) {...}
```

I know about ArgumentCaptor, but I'm just trying to make it work like this as i believe the matcher ***eq()*** is used here to check the equals of the value passed for **both** the arguments. Or is it causing issue because it is object.

Will it be possible to verify like this? Thanks.

Comment: It's not quite clear what behavior you're looking for. Yes, `eq()` checks equality, and no, Object isn't the problem; `eq()` uses `Object.equals(Object)`, which applies to all objects. The error message makes it look like `setData` is being called exactly once with the wrong arguments, not twice the way you're expecting.

Comment: Yes, the issue was that the method was called with different arguments as my test was not initialized properly with @Before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with my code as my test was not initialized properly with @Before.